# Which linear equation algorithm requires less memory than LAPACK in general? Can I use it in R or RcppArmadillo?

Tags: c++, r, armadillo, linear-equation

I am trying to solve a linear system, Ax = b in R. A is a 111779 by 111779 sparse matrix or "dgCMatrix" and contains 10^11 elements. b is a 111779 by 1 dense matrix. I used a powerful AWS ec2 instance to calculate this.

First I used solve() in R but it returned "problem too large". Then I used the function SparseM::solve() but still could not get the result due to the lack of memory. Finally I used RcppArmadillo::spsolve( , ,"lapacks"), which means "sparse matrix solve" with LAPACK algorithm. It returned "SpMat::init(): requested size is too large".

```r
rcpp_inc <- '
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
'
src <- '
mat Y0 = as<mat>(Y);
sp_mat X0 = as<sp_mat>(X);
mat out = spsolve(X0, Y0,"lapacks");
return(wrap(out));
'
fn <- cxxfunction(signature(Y="Matrix", X="Matrix"), src, 
                  plugin='RcppArmadillo', rcpp_inc)
res <- fn(b, A)
```

Actually the function works well when A is smaller. If I cannot use more memory, is it possible to solve the equation? What kind of software or algorithm shall I use?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Since you use `SparseM::solve`, I assume that your matrix is symmetric positive definite. If you have a limited number of vectors, you can use a [conjugate gradient algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method). Indeed, its a purely itterative procedure and it only only require a couple a copies of the vector. Light preconditionners like Jacobi or SSOR are available and feature a memory footprint comparable to that of a vector.

Comment: As specified in http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#spsolve , `For "lapack", sparse matrix A is converted to a dense matrix before using the LAPACK solver; this considerably increases memory usage`. If you want to try a real sparse solver, you may try to install superLU, enable ARMA_USE_SUPERLU in config.hpp . There is also a comprehensive collection of direct and itterative sparse solver implemented in or interfaced to the PETSc library https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/linearsolvertable.html

Comment: @francis, thank you for your comments. I tried conjugate gradient algorithm by using Rlinsolve::lsolve.cg() but it returns error: cannot allocate vector of size 93.1 Gb. In my linear system, A is less than 150Mb, b is small too. Why does the algorithm cost so much memory?

Comment: @francis , the main problem in RcppArmadillo is that the sparse matrix cannot be initialized because the requested size is too large. Before the algorithm is used, the software has stopped.

Comment: The size of 93.1Gb corresponds to a 111779 by 111779 dense matrix. It is clearly unexpected. The preconditioner could be provided as a sparse matrix: I don't know R enough to know whether the default value `diag(ncol(A))` creates a dense matrix or not. If your matrix is already symmetric, try `adjsym=FALSE`.  Finally, looking at the source https://github.com/cran/Rlinsolve/blob/master/R/lsolve_CG.R , you may try to directly call `linsolve.cg.single.sparse()`.

Comment: The cpp implementation is in https://github.com/cran/Rlinsolve/blob/master/src/krylov_cg.cpp and there is a line `z = spsolve(M,r,"lapack");`... This is clearly not a good idea, as it generates a dense matrix. You could try to start from this code and change it, replacing this line by `z=r` (no preconditionning)...

Comment: You could have a try with `cgsolve_sparseOMP` or `pcgsolve_sparseOMP` available at https://github.com/styvon/cPCG. See if that does the trick for your problem size...

Comment: @TomWenseleers Thank you for your package. This looks decent. Actually I solved this problem using RcppEigen. Your functions are definitely valuable for Armadillo users.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! Maybe you could post the code you used to solve your problem as an answer, because I am sure it would be useful for other users, maybe with a comparison of the timing you get with pcgsolve_sparseOMP...